# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to train a model but every time it throws up this error. The error usually occurs when training on Google Colab but when training on my local PC it just runs normally.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-3435b262f1ae> in <module>()
----> 1 trainer.train()

8 frames
/content/lstm_chem/trainer.py in train(self)
     43             # use_multiprocessing=True,
     44             shuffle=True,
---> 45             callbacks=self.callbacks)
     46 
     47         last_weight_file = glob(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    813           workers=workers,
    814           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
--> 815           model=self)
    816 
    817       # Container that configures and calls `tf.keras.Callback`s.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model)
   1110         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1111         distribution_strategy=ds_context.get_strategy(),
-> 1112         model=model)
   1113 
   1114     strategy = ds_context.get_strategy()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, shuffle, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, model, **kwargs)
    906         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    907         model=model,
--> 908         **kwargs)
    909 
    910   @staticmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, model, **kwargs)
    790       return tensor_shape.TensorShape([None for _ in shape.as_list()])
    791 
--> 792     output_shapes = nest.map_structure(_get_dynamic_shape, peek)
    793     output_types = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t.dtype, peek)
    794 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    615 
    616   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 617       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    618       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    619 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    615 
    616   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 617       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    618       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    619 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _get_dynamic_shape(t)
    784 
    785     def _get_dynamic_shape(t):
--> 786       shape = t.shape
    787       # Unknown number of dimensions, `as_list` cannot be called.
    788       if shape.rank is None:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

This is the code, any assistance will be highly appreciated

```py
from glob import glob
import os
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard

class LSTMChemTrainer(object):
    def __init__(self, modeler, train_data_loader, valid_data_loader):
        self.model = modeler.model
        self.config = modeler.config
        self.train_data_loader = train_data_loader
        self.valid_data_loader = valid_data_loader
        self.callbacks = []
        self.init_callbacks()

    def init_callbacks(self):
        self.callbacks.append(
            ModelCheckpoint(
                filepath=os.path.join(
                    self.config.checkpoint_dir,
                    '%s-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5' %
                    self.config.exp_name),
                monitor=self.config.checkpoint_monitor,
                mode=self.config.checkpoint_mode,
                save_best_only=self.config.checkpoint_save_best_only,
                save_weights_only=self.config.checkpoint_save_weights_only,
                verbose=self.config.checkpoint_verbose,
            ))
        self.callbacks.append(
            TensorBoard(
                log_dir=self.config.tensorboard_log_dir,
                write_graph=self.config.tensorboard_write_graph,
            ))

    def train(self):
        history = self.model.fit(
            self.train_data_loader,
            steps_per_epoch=self.train_data_loader.__len__(),
            epochs=self.config.num_epochs,
            verbose=self.config.verbose_training,
            validation_data=self.valid_data_loader,
            validation_steps=self.valid_data_loader.__len__(),
            shuffle=True,
            callbacks=self.callbacks)

        last_weight_file = glob(
            os.path.join(
                f'{self.config.checkpoint_dir}',
                f'{self.config.exp_name}-{self.config.num_epochs:02}*.hdf5')
        )[0]

        assert os.path.exists(last_weight_file)
        self.config.model_weight_filename = last_weight_file

        with open(os.path.join(self.config.exp_dir, 'config.json'), 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.config.toJSON(indent=2))
```

Comment: I am experiencing a similar traceback, I suspect this has to with the fact we are both using generators and callbacks. I am running on the tensorflow/tensorflow-gpu:latest docker image, will let you know if I resolve it.

Comment: does your train_data_loader return or yeild a [None]? If so, try removing it.

Comment: The issue maybe with the model files from the colab, if you have mounted your drive to colab and loading file from drive make sure you follow the path defined as per colab for your code. Follow this link to mount drive to colab and load files from drive https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/download-anything-to-google-drive-using-google-colab/